# Build app with ExtJS and Spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, sencha-cmd, extjs6-classic

I am learning ExtJS framework, for experiments I use on front-end side ExtJS and on back-end side JavaEE Spring framework (it is configured like as REST service). 
 So, I start my front-end part on localhost:1841 and back-end part on localhost:8080. Question is:

> How I can say to ExtJS.Store that requests need to send to
>   localhost:8080/** instead of localhost:1841/**?

Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ExtJS have **[`singleton`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-singleton)** you can use this class.

**Singleton** pattern is a design pattern  which restricts instantiation of a class to only one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed across the system. The Singleton pattern provides a single point of access to a particular instance. Implementation of a singleton pattern must satisfy the single instance and global access principles.

> For this "How I can say to ExtJS.Store that requests need to send to localhost:8080/** instead of localhost:1841/**?"

You can use in your app like below code :

> Firstly create `singletone` class

```
/*
 * Create singletone class in your application
 * This class you can access in your application anywhere you want within the app.
 * Usage: 
 * commonUtility.getServerUrl();// whatever property you have defined inside of config you can access like this
 */
Ext.define('APPNAME.utils.SingleToneClassName', {
    alternateClassName: 'commonUtility',
    singleton: true,
    config: {
        /*
         * you can put local or live also or whatever you want.
         * for local it will be ip address like this {'http://192.168.30.83:8080/'}
         * for live is will be live tomcate  host  url {http://example.com/}
         */
        serverURL: 'http://192.168.30.83:8080/'
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this;

        me.initConfig(config);
    },
});
```

> Create/Define your store

```
//Your store
Ext.define('APPNAME.store.StoreName', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['your fields here'],
    storeId: 'storeIdHere',
    alias: "store.storeAliasHere",
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: commonUtility.getServerUrl() + 'your Server Method name here', //Based on your server URL acceptance
        withCredentials: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            keepRawData: true
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true, //If you need auto load then put true otherwise false
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store, operation, options) {
            //If you have token based authenthication then you need to put like below
            store.getProxy().setHeaders({
                "x-auth-token": 'your token here'
            });
            //If you have need to pass some  parameter in API method then you can pass like below
            store.getProxy().extraParams.your_parameter_name = 'value';
        }
    },
});

//If you want to load your store on some event or any other functions
//then

Ext.getStore('your_storeId_herer').load({
    url: commonUtility.getServerUrl() + 'your Server Method name here', //Based on your server URL acceptance
    params: {
        //If you have need to pass some params in server side then 
        //you put here like
        name: 'value'
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you. for more details you can refer **[ExtJS6.x](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/)** Docs